# join() or append to the end of a URL with jquery or javascript in Shopify Framework

Tags: jquery, url, href, shopify

I would like to add "+20-30" to the end of my URL below when clicking a button.

Currently I have:
mydomain.com/collections/mens/white

I would like my URL to be
mydomain.com/collections/mens/white+20-30

```
   <div class="clearfix filter">
            {% assign tags = 'White, Grey, Tan, Neutral, Blue, Black' | replace: ' ,', ',' | replace: ', ', ',' | split: ',' %}
            <p>Filter Color</p>
             <div id="dd" class="mywrap-dropdown-2" tabindex="2">Select
                    <ul class="dropdowner" id="coll-filter">
                        <li><a href="">All</a></li>
                        {% for tag in tags %}
                      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                      <li><a href="{{ tag | handle }}" class="selected">{{ tag }}</li>
                      {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}
                      <li><a href="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</li>
                      {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>   
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#coll-filter li a').on('click', function () {
  var newTags = [];
  jQuery('#coll-filter li a').each(function() { 
    if (jQuery(this).attr('href')) {
    newTags.push(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
  }
});
 if (newTags.length) {
   var query = newTags.join('+');
   var newhref = jQuery('{{ 'tag' | link_to_tag: 'tag'    }}').attr('href').replace('tag', query);
    jQuery(this).attr("href", newhref)
   } 
  else {
     {% if collection.handle %}
     window.location.href = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
      {% elsif collection.products.first.type == collection.title %}
    window.location.href = '{{ collection.title | url_for_type }}';
     {% elsif collection.products.first.vendor == collection.title %}
    window.location.href = '{{ collection.title | url_for_vendor }}';
    {% endif %}

  }
 });
```

Comment: You want to update the URL of the page? This *will* trigger a page-reload..?

Comment: Hi David, I am working in Shopify and just pulled out this snippet..There is more code but I wanted to simplify it.

Comment: That's almost entirely irrelevant (sorry); what is it that you're trying to update, the `href` attribute of an `a` element, or the URL of the current page (in the address-bar of the browser)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var newhefc = $(this).attr('href') + '+20-30';
$(this).attr('href', newhefc);
```

Or more directly:

```
$(this).attr( 'href', $(this).attr('href') + '+20-30' );
```

---

Looking at your edit, all else being equal and working, if you merely wanted to add a fixed string, it should be

```
jQuery(this).attr("href", newhref + '+20-30')
```

Comment: What I have above returns all the "tags" which is the issue I'm running into. Resulting in this:http://mydomain.com/collections/mens/t-shirts+t-shirts+white+white+grey+grey+blue+blue+black+black+20-30+20-30

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're updating the `href` of a link:

```
$(this).attr('href', function(i,h) { return h + '+20-30'; });
```

Or, more simply:

```
this.href += '+20-30';
```

jQuery isn't *always* necessary, though it's important to remember that the jQuery method will return exactly what's found within the `href` attribute, whereas the native DOM approach (the second example) will return an absolute/'parsed' full URL.

(These examples include the explicit assumption that `this` (and therefore `$(this)`) reference the relevant `a` element of which you're trying to update the `href` attribute.)

Comment: I will edit what I have abouve and post the block of code, what I have is returning all the tags?

Comment: Okay, and what HTML does that produce? Where are you trying to update the `href` (and I'm *still* only *assuming* that it's an `href`, you've not confirmed, or denied, that assumption...)? Is this a templating system you're using (if it is, I'm afraid I can't parse it in my head). Add whatever templating/library you're using as a tag to the question then you'll (almost certainly) get users more familiar with that syntax looking at your question.

Comment: I am using using multiple tag filters in shopify. When you select on option I would like to be able to filter another and another. Resulting in something like this: mydomain.com/collections/mens/white+20-30

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://wiki.shopify.com/Link_to_tag

This creates the url for you using liquid.

Comment: Thanks BBG. I am using this here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Filtering_a_collection_with_more_than_one_product_tag_drop-downs But, have a custom drop-down menu that doesnt use select. The example uses select I need "click"